# Calibrating FEETECH FR5311M Digital Servo

Tags: arduino, adc, servo, robotics, calibration

[image: FEETECH FR5311M (digital servo)]

Hey everyone,
I am owning this model feetch servo motor.

I want to do the following:(with arduino uno)

1. Read the initial position(angle) of the servo motor
2. rotate the motor to desired position(angle) and stop it
3. read the final postion also to which motor is driven (angle)

I tried reading the analog values through the feedback wire in arduino , but found those values to be random. So it is not clear to me , how to do the above steps with a random ADC feedback values. How do I calibrate in such a situation?

https://learn.adafruit.com/analog-feedback-servos/using-feedback

I used the above link to calibrate the Servo motor. In this case my Servo rotates clockwise and anti-clockwise to the same position which was initially set and then starts continuously rotating after finishing the previous task.

Please do help!

Information about the servo: http://www.feetechrc.com/product/continuous-rotation-servo/two-working-mode-digital-programmable-metal-gears-servo-fr5311m/

Comment: you have not provided sufficient information ... please add a link to the datasheet to your question ... **do not add to comments**

Comment: Information about the feedback wire on these specially modified FeeTech servos is 'sketchy' (none of the datasheets I found mentioned it). Apparently it gets a voltage directly off the feedback pot. If you manually move the servo arm to different positions and read the voltage on this wire with a multimeter, what do you get? Is your servo programmed for continuous rotation? How are you powering the servo?

Comment: I am trying to that , I am powering if from arduino. No not continuous rotation , want to stop it when it reaches the desired position using the ADC values from the feedback wire. But sometimes the adc values fluctuate , while moving the servo